# Need passwordless rsync -- remote server doesn't allow ssh keyfiles

Tags: ssh, rsync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [rsync with script supplied password](https://serverfault.com/questions/86081/rsync-with-script-supplied-password)

I have a process that makes several rsync calls to the same server because I have to copy several files locally into different directories remotely.  The remote server does not accept ssh keyfiles for authentication.

Is it possible to:

- automate the password phrase for rsync,
- or allow multiple source/destinations pairs for one rsync invocation?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate and answer found here: [rsync with script supplied password](https://serverfault.com/questions/86081/rsync-with-script-supplied-password)